# order from collectionType in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm new to symfony2 and I'm just trying to figure how the framework functions.
I have the following relationship:

```
1 palette(Palette entity) contains exactly 256 plumes(LogicalPlume entity) 
( which refers to a color(PhysicalPlume entity) ).
PS: the ID of the row in db is set as auto-increment, 
but the index of logicalPlume and physicalPlume is set manually (0->255).
```

I set the relationship in my entities as oneToMany and ManyToOne.
I created the `PaletteType` as having a `CollectionType`:

```
$builder->add('logicalPlumes', 'collection', array(
  'type' => new LogicalPlumeType($profile_id),
  'label' => 'plumes'
));
```

and the `LogicalPlumeType`

```
$profile_id = $this->profile_id;

$builder->add('physicalPlume', 'entity', array(
  'class' => 'DessinPlumeBundle:PhysicalPlume',
  'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er)  use ($profile_id) {
     return $er->createQueryBuilder('pp')
                            ->where("pp.profile = :profile")
                          ->orderBy('pp.index', 'ASC')
                     ->setParameter('profile', $profile_id);
   }
));
```

Eveything is great, the palette object is persisted correctly in the database (except that the objects are not saved in their proper indexes).

Firebug tells me the select beside label '0' has ID of "palette_0".
but I think this actually points to another index in the database, doesnt it ?!

So, when I read the object, I want the plumes returned by INDEX so that I can display them correctly.

For example:

```
I saved 
logicalPlume1 = 10;
logicalPlume2 = 0;   with '0' being the default value.
logicalPlume3 = 9;
logicalPlume4 = 0;
logicalPlume5 = 5;

when i read it back, it shows:
logicalPlume1 = 10;
logicalPlume2 = 5;
logicalPlume3 = 9;
logicalPlume4 = 0;
logicalPlume5 = 0;
pushing all the '0' values to the bottom
```

I think I should use that `CollectionType` here, but I have an order to preserve.
How do I do that ?

Do I need to use another type maybe??

thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could try using [INDEX BY](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by) in your query.

Comment: Hi gregOire, thx for your reply.
actually, i do have an "orderBy" on the query i have, and it works fine for getting the LogicalPlumeType fine.
my problem is with PaletteType, where i do not have a query... i just want that collection to allow me to say in what order this collection's items are returned...

Comment: `INDEX BY` != `ORDER BY`

Comment: This comment aimed at answering this question : "I want the plumes returned by INDEX so that I can display them correctly?"

Comment: Ok, i went to try it, but that was not a part of "QueryBuilder" class.. where and how do i insert it in case i need to...? any ideas ??

Comment: Try replacing `'pp'` with `'pp INDEX BY pp.whatever_you_want'`

Comment: return $er->createQueryBuilder('pp INDEX BY pp.index')
->where("pp.profile = :profile")
->setParameter('profile', $profile_id)
no good

Comment: Please use backticks when putting code in comments. Please provide error messages if you want some help, I'm not going to try this piece of code to see what it outputs, am I? And please, make full sentences. I'm helping you, I'm the one that should be writing "error msg plz".

Comment: sorry about the code format.. and sorry i made you feel uncomfortable.. seems like i dont have control over the answer layout (dont know how to put a line break...)
the error is:
_[Semantical Error] line 0, col 16 near 'BY pp.index FROM': Error: Class 'BY' is not defined._
while having the query:
`return $er->createQueryBuilder('pp INDEX BY pp.index') ->where("pp.profile = :profile")->setParameter('profile', $profile_id)`

Comment: I think you should try this : `$er->createQueryBuilder()->from('Fully\Qualified\Namespace\To\Your\PhysicalPlume\Entity', 'pp INDEX BY pp.index')`

Comment: _Warning: Missing argument 1 for Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder(), called in LogicalPlumeType.php_.
it did not work as expected...

Comment: Have you tried leaving the alias? `$er->createQueryBuilder('pp')->from('Fully\Qualified\Namespace\To\Your\PhysicalPlume\Entity', 'pp INDEX BY pp.index')` looks funny, but worth a try I think.

Comment: _[Semantical Error] line 0, col 91 near 'pp INDEX BY pp.index': Error: 'pp' is already defined. _
IMHO, i think i do not need to specify the entity once again because it's already defined in the 'class' property...
don't you agree..??

Comment: Yes, seems right, but then I don't see how to add this 'INDEX BY'...

Comment: what is this "index by" that you keep emphasizing on ??
are you sure this is what i need.. ?? can it be what i need .. ??

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about it, No I'm not sure, I just used something similar in Doctrine 1, and yes it can be what you need when asking "I want the plumes returned by INDEX so that I can display them correctly?" . For the bigger problem, I don't know if it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your controller code, I would say your cascade persist is not processed in the same order as the non-default values you choose for your form.

Try persisting each plume via foreach or map and see what the indices are.

Please post controller code if you still need help with this.